# Cakephp 2.9 Internal 500 server error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

I got a project for some enhancement which is running on **CakePHP 2.9**.

which is a ERP for govt Hospitals, i need work on admin panel for some enhancements.

I copied the project folder in **localhost**

`/var/www/html/`

and already imported **schema** into my phpmyadmin  named **esic**.

and then i configured my `esic/app/config/database.php` file to the database(`esic`).

When I'm accessing the project from localhost, it is showing an error.

`localhost/esic/`

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I read the issue on Google and CakePHP official site but I didn't understand anything.
Please help me to figure out this problem.

Please let me know if some other details required.

> Note: All other projects are working fine.

Comment: Hi, sorry, but think about it. If you cannot solve a misconfiguration locally, how are we going to be any help when we have No Real Idea about your site or what you have done or how you have configured it.

Comment: sir,please check edits

Comment: Check apache error log. it will tell exact cause of error. In linux you can find log in ```/var/log/apache2/error.log```

Comment: Thank you karan, it's showing me **Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration**

Comment: Have you enabled debugging in the Cake config file?

Answer (score 0):

500 internal server occurs when the desired file or URL is not accessible.

AS you said all other projects are running on your localhost then please check that your .htaccess file is correct on this project.

Or else check other URL of the project.

Link: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Comment: Thank you Dhruv, other URL also not working,  as i saw into .htaccess file, official domain is written in RewriteCond and RewriteRule.

Comment: If issue has been solved then you can vote up to my answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux environment try maybe only the permission of the folder. I somehow encounter that problem.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/esic
             or
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/esic
```